# tbody tag element and DOM

Tags: c#, html, browser

i want to use HtmlAgilityPack with WebBrowser control, but i have a problem. DOM is different because IE adds tbody tag element after table. Why? How i can disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, the `tbody` element is required. The start and end tags are, however, optional (as are those of the html, body and head elements, and the end tag for p, td, li and numerous others).

You just need to write your code to be able to handle both cases (or include the tbody tags explicitly)